# Constructing a regular expression to wrap images with <a>

Tags: html, regex

A web page contains lots of image elements:

```
<img src="myImage.gif" width="180" height="18" />
```

But they may not be very well-formed, for example, the width or height attribute may be missing. And it also may not be properly closed with /. The src attribute is always there.

I need a regular expression that wraps these  with a hyperlink having href set to the src of the img.

```
<a href="myImage.gif" target="_blank"><img src="myImage.gif" width="180" height="18" /></a>
```

I can successfully locate the images using this regexp in this editor: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/:

```
<img src="([^<]*)"[^<]*>
```

But what is the next step?

Comment: which language are you looking for?

Comment: Just curious, shouldn't it be `...[^>]*>`?

Comment: @polygenelubricants Changing [^<] to [^>] or [^<>] should be fine because these two characters should not appear in those places anyway.

Comment: @rtpHarry not any one particular language, I just didn't know how to refer to those captured groups but I think I know now. Thank you.

Comment: just to point out, I don't know if you realised this yet, but different languages have different implementations of regex such as POSIX, .net, javascript all have variations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DOM-based method is best, *but if that regex works* (not easy to accomplish for general HTML input) to match the desired `<img>` elements, with the value of the `src` attribute captured in `\1`, then just replace the whole match (captured in `\0`) with:

```
<a href="\1" target="_blank">\0</a>
```

In Java, the backreferences in replacement string will be `$0` and `$1`; I'm not sure what language you're using so adjust accordingly.

In Java, though, something like this would work:

```
String imgHrefed = str.replaceAll(
   "<img src=\"([^<]*)\"[^<]*>",
   "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$0</a>"
);
```

---

It wasn't clear from your question what to do with any other attributes that the `<img>` may have. The above replacement keeps them as they are. If you also want to rewrite them (i.e. you're not *just* wrapping `<img>` in an `<a>` anymore), then perhaps you want to rewrite to this:

```
<a href="\1" target="_blank"><img src="\1" width="180" height="18" /></a>
```

Comment: All answers are quite similar, since this one gets the most votes, I follow the majority that this is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, use [string.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) with `$1` being the part you matched:

```
str.replace(/<img src="([^<]*)"[^<]*>/, 
    '"<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img src="$1" width="180" height="18" /></a>')
```

Or better still capture the whole `image` tag (now the src is `$2` since it's in the second capture):

```
s.replace(/(<img src="([^<]*)"[^<]*>)/, '"<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>')
```

Comment: I am not working in javascript but this should be a useful one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In .net the regex is basically the same as javascript in most cases but the notation of the surrounding code would be slightly different.

```
    string imageHtmlSnippet = @"<img src=""myImage.gif"" width=""180"" height=""18"" />";
    string imageHtmlReplacement = @"<a href=""$1"" target=""_blank""><img src=""$1"" width=""180"" height=""18"" /></a>";

    Regex findImages = new Regex(@"<img src=""([^<]*)""[^<]*>");

    string fixedHtmlSnippet = findImages.Replace(imageHtmlSnippet, imageHtmlReplacement);
```

HOWEVER - this regex will fail if the src isn't the first attribute on the tag. I dont have time to fix it because I should already be out the door :)

In truth you should be looking to a html parsing library such as HtmlAgilityPack to parse it (if you are working in .net):

- http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/search/label/HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: I am not working in any particular language. I am just using that editor and try to wrap the images with a hyperlink in a html document. But your code snippets should be useful when I work in .NET. Thank you.